# Is there any good communication protocol/rules for socket communication between server and client

Tags: sockets, protocols, communication

I am developing a socket based software. The client asks a question and the server answers the question and I have some problems.

1. The client asks a "question" to the server, the server may receive the "question" after 2 minutes. Then the client may ask the "question" once more  1 minute after it asked for the first time. So how to avoid the server answering twice?
2. If the server answers the client, the client may receive the answer immediately because of the network delay. So the client may ask the server once again. Server receives the question, then answers again.
3. Is there any good communication protocol/rules for this application?

Comment: how many responses is the client now expecting?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid sending duplicate answers you can use a nonce. Select an integer and send it to the server, together with the question data. When answering, the server will attach the same integer to it's answer. The client should drop all received answers with duplicated nonce values.

Answer (score 0):

If you somehow store questions server side, it should be easy to just check the last questions asked, so that you avoid sending or receiving questions twice. Unless you have very limited server resources, or you have a lot of traffic, this solution should work for you.

You might also give each visitor to the site an ID, and store the questions from each ID in a format that is easy to search though and find possible duplicates.

As for the protocol, basic HTTP or Websocket is a good protocol for sending requests back and forth.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API